# Erro: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python, self

Sou iniciante em Python e estou desenvolvendo meu primeiro programa. Ele está assim:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font

class Application(Frame):
 def __init__(self, master=None):
 pass
 self.msg = Label(self, text="Bem vindos a GUIDA!!", fg = 'blue', font = 'Candara')
self.msg.place(x=50,y=70)
self.bye = Button (self, text="Bye", command=self.quit)
self.bye.pack ()
self.pack()
self.msg_2 = Label(self, text="Selecione os tópicos e exclareça suas dúvidas!", fg = 'black', font = 'Candara')
self.msg_2.place(x=80,y=100)
self.view = Button (self, text="Ver Tópicos", font = "Algerian", command = comando, fg = 'black', bg = 'white', activebackground = 'white', activeforeground = 'yellow')
self.view.place(x=400,y=100)

root = Tk()

root["bg"] = "green"

root.title('GUIDA')

root.geometry('750x700')

app = Application()

mainloop()
```

Mas quando vou executar, ele abre assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria saber como se resolve esse erro.

Comment: Evite postar seus códigos em imagem, edite sua pergunta e coloque-os aqui

Comment: Por favor, [não poste seu código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/132), o site possui suporte para a formatação do mesmo; você pode obter mais informações fazendo o [tour], lendo o guia de [ask] e acessando a [help]. O erro em questão se dá porque você está passando para o inicializador de `Label` uma variável `self` que não existe e isso parece estar errado mesmo se ela existisse. O parâmetro `self` é definido implicitamente pela linguagem quando você instancia uma classe, você dificilmente precisa definí-lo diretamente.

Comment: oq faço @AndersonCarlosWoss?

Comment: Comece estudando e entendendo o que é e como funciona o `self`. No link que marquei há um material bom para você iniciar os estudos.

Comment: Lima, Cara pelo que parece aqui é apenas sua identação, quando você usa o self ele não estão dentro do bloco do método __init__ tente corrigir a identação e veja se funciona. De acordo com a PEP8 o python trabalha com 4 espaços de identação, e se você não respeitar a indentação seu código vai falhar.